# Apex:relatedlist pageSize attribute is working for other users except for the creator of the code

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, related-list

I'm trying to create a custom related list enclosed in a VF Component that was called in a VF page using apex:relatedlist and I'm having trouble with the functionality of the pageSize.

```
<apex:relatedList subject="{!acctRec}"  list="Contacts" pageSize="5" />
```

I've set the pageSize to 5 for example for Contacts but whenever I look at the VF page it shows more than 5 records in the Contacts related list so in short it is not working. But when a colleague of mine logged in on the same org and checked the same VF page, the pageSize is working. He also tried to log in as other system admin users in our org and the pageSize is working  it shows only 5 records but only not for me as the user. Does anyone have any thoughts or experience about this? I'll greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

This is what other users see(only the 5 records):
[image]

This is what I see:
[image]

Comment: so you see more than 5 records in the related list ? how many?

Comment: there are like 30+ records in the Alerts related list. When I am the user, I see all those 30+ records but when the other users were logged in even if not system admin users they only see 5 records for the Alerts related list.

Comment: other users see only 5 records per one page, and you see 30 records per one page?

Comment: yes that's the case

Comment: I'm not really sure if it's because I'm the creator of the code because I'm having the same issue with other VF pages created by other users with apex:relatedlist and pageSize functions.

Comment: will you be able to take a screenshot: first, as your user, second, login in as another user and edit question to add those images?

Comment: I already provided some screenshots above in my original comment. I also changed the object to Contacts.